# Is there a API version of .getBackgrounds() such as Values.Get() vs getValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, read-write

With some community support I recently learned how much faster `Values.Get()` is versus `getValues()`. I've been upgrading one of my projects code to use these new commands. As I go through and try to change over all of my read/write commands I've found that I use `.getBackgrounds()`. I haven't been able to find the equivalent API command to get the background colors. I presume it doesn't exist and that I'll need to continue to use `.getBackgrounds()`. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Sheets.Spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) which gives you a [spreadsheet json](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet). Backgrounds will be at

```
sheets[].data[].rowData[].values[].cellData.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor
```

Comment: I realize this is now delayed but will using the spreadsheet json be faster than .getBackgrounds just like Values.Get() compared to getValues()?

Comment: @LANCE yes.`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: I've added additional questions to the original post in relation to your above suggested commands.

Comment: @LANCE Please ask a new question. Also consider reading about JavaScript objects in MDN before asking. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Comment: Now that I've used `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get` to get the JSON and make adjustments to it. What is the equivalent API command to `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update` to update the background colors in the RGBA format?