# Calling Background colors from google sheets using Google sheets api is missing data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color, google-sheets-api

From a previous question linked here ( [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711616/is-there-a-api-version-of-getbackgrounds-such-as-values-get-vs-getvalues/63714047?noredirect=1#comment113163883_63714047) ) I learned about Sheets.SpreadSheets.get calling a JSON of sheet data that would allow me to get the backgroundcolors of a sheet within my project. Id previously been doing this with `var BackgroundColors = ActiveWeekSheet.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();` but was told that the JSON method would be a faster read/write method. They directed me to do some reading on Javascript objects but after that I'm still confused.

I've got the following code. `TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1irmcO8yMxYwkcLaxZd1cN8XsTIhpzI98If_Cxgp1vF8");` which seems to call a JSON with sheet specific data. A logger statement of `TestArray` returns this: `testArrayObject: {"properties":{"gridProperties":{"rowCount":1000,"columnCount":26},"sheetType":"GRID","index":0,"sheetId":0,"title":"Awesome"}}`

Community members previously suggested I could then find the background colors at: `sheets[].data[].rowData[].values[].cellData.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor`

I've highlighted one of the cells yellow but when reviewing the above JSON i can't seem to find anything that references color. There definitely isn't any multileveling of the JSON to refer to sheets->data->rowData->values->celldata.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor.

What am I missing here? Do I need to format things someway? Am I not calling the right JSON to start with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get),

> By default, data within grids will not be returned. You can include grid data one of two ways:

> - Specify a field mask listing your desired fields using the fields URL parameter in HTTP

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {
  ranges:"Sheet1!A1:A5",
  fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
})
```

> - Set the includeGridData URL parameter to true. If a field mask is set, the includeGridData parameter is ignored

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {
  ranges:"Sheet1!A1:A5",
  includeGridData: true
})
```

- [Field mask documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#partial_responses):

> In a nutshell,
>
> - multiple different fields are comma separated, and
> - subfields are dot-separated.
> - For convenience, multiple subfields from the same type can be listed within parentheses.

- You may test the API [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22SPREADSHEET_ID%22%2C%22ranges%22%3A%5B%22Sheet1!A1%3AA5%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))%22%7D#try-it)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to use your direction to get the color information. It returns this: testArray: `{"sheets":[{"data":[{"rowData":[{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1}}}]},{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}}]},{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}}]}]}]}]}.` I presumed this would return an array but I can't seem to cycle through it normally or get it's `.length`. Is this an array?

Comment: @LANCE You need to learn to parse objects and arrays. Read the link  I've asked you to read before. This is a object with key `"sheets"` with value of `array`s, which in turn contain  multiple levels of nested arrays and objects. To get to the first color's red value, you'd use something like `response.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].effectiveFormat.backgroundColor.red`Also see [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  JavaScript guides.

Answer (score 0):

There are optional parameters in the [spreadsheets.get method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) that will give you that data, but you need to explicitly include them:

- `ranges` – The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
- `includeGridData` – The cell data within specified range.

This specifies a range of just one cell (A1 in Sheet1), but you can specify a larger range and navigate through the array if you need to.

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(SS_ID, {ranges: "Sheet1!A1", includeGridData: true});
```

Really important that you keep in mind this returns a [Color object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color) with RGBA
values that range from 0-1, but elsewhere apps script uses [hex color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) or the [conventional 0-255 RGB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred,-green,-blue) values.